# How can I open dialog depending on conditions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, calendar, material-ui

I'm using React-Calendar and made it can add schedule.
I want to open material ui dialog depending on 2 conditions,
opening form dialog when there is no title, and show schedule dialog when title has.
My calendar look like this.

[image]

the problem is form dialog open when I click the day title has,
and I guess because "setSelectDay" is not working so "selectDay" has no data.

```
const Calendar = () => {
  const [title, setTitle] = useState("");
  const [selectDay, setSelectDay] = useState("");
  const [database, setDatabase] = useState([]);

  //form dialog
  const [openAdd, setOpenAdd] = useState(false);
  //show schedule dialog
  const [openSchedule, setOpenSchedule] = useState(false);

 // formate change + open dialog
  const handleChange = (date) => {
    date.getTimezoneOffset();
    date.setMinutes(date.getMinutes() + 540);
    var changes = date.toISOString().slice(0, 10);
    setSelectDay(changes);

    console.log(selectDay);  // has no data

    if(selectDay === "") {
      setOpenAdd(true);
    }
    else {
      setOpenSchedule(true);
    }
  } 

  useEffect(() => {
    const getData = async () => {
      const response = await axios.get('api/calendar');
        console.log(response.data);
        setDatabase(response.data);
      }
      getData();
  },[]);

  const show schedule dialog = () => {
    axios
    .post(`api/calendar`, {
        title: title,
        date: selectDay,
        description: description
    })
    .then(res => {
      alert("Info added successfully");
      location.reload();
    })
    .catch(err => {
      alert(“failed”);
    }); 
  }

  // display title on calendar
  const getTileContent = (calendar) => {
    let year = calendar.date.getFullYear();
    let month = calendar.date.getMonth() + 1;
    let day = calendar.date.getDate();
    month = ('0' + month).slice(-2);
    day = ('0' + day).slice(-2);
    const formatDate = (year + '-' + month + '-' + day);

    let message = "";

    database.forEach(element => {
      if(formatDate === element.date) {
         message = element.title;
      }
    });
    return (
      <p>{message}</p>
    );
  }

    return(
        <>
          <Calendars
            value={value}
            onChange={handleChange}
            tileContent={getTileContent}
            className={classes.calendarUi}
          />

          {/* form dialog */}
          <Dialog open={openAdd} onClose={handleClose} aria-labelledby="form-dialog-title">
            <DialogContent>
              <p>date: {selectDay}</p>
              <TextField
                label=“title”
                onChange={inputTitle}
                fullWidth
              />
              <TextField
                label=“description”
                onChange={inputDescription}
                fullWidth
              />
            </DialogContent>
            <DialogActions>
              <Button onClick={addSchedule} color="primary">
                Add
              </Button>
            </DialogActions>
          </Dialog>

          {/* show schedule dialog */}
          <Dialog open={openSchedule} onClose={handleClose} aria-labelledby="form-dialog-title">
            <DialogContent>
              <p>{database.title}</p>
              <p>{database.description}</p>
            </DialogContent>
          </Dialog>

        </>
    )
}

export default Calendar
```

Does anyone know why setSelectDay is not working and how can I fix it?
Thank you.

Comment: The argument of an event based trigger IS the event. Try to `console.log(data)` in your `handleChange()` function. I'm pretty sure you're not having a date.

Comment: you mean selectDay? I did console.log(selectDay); and no data here. How can I use selectDay after updating(get axios data)?

Comment: Ok I'm not sure I've checked the right library (can you put some details or link about the library you're using). But from what I understood, you'll need to change a state with your calendar THEN apply your logic (open the dialog). I suggest you use a `useEffect` hook.

Comment: I'm using this library. https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-calendar
Do you mean I need to change value in calendar before apply handleChange,right? Thank you. I'll try.

Comment: The `onChange` attribute of react-calendar is waiting for a `useState` generated callback. It will change the associated state. Stick to this so you are sure you are not off track. Then by using `useEffect` hook with a dependency on the state, you can do your logic and trigger other state changes (not on the same state object unless it will be an infinite loop) and display your dialog.